# Jenkins - Permission denied on folder

Tags: jenkins, centos

I have a jenkins running on CentOS 8 and a simple job who should write something in a text file.

```
echo "Hello" > /home/dev/Git/Test.txt
```

The target directory should be `Git`:

```
[dev@h2899618 ~]$ ls -l /home/dev/
insgesamt 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 dev dev 4096  7. Okt 20:54 Git
```

The user `dev` has the following permissions:

```
[dev@h2899618 ~]$ /usr/bin/id
uid=1002(dev) gid=1002(dev) Gruppen=1002(dev),10(wheel),48(apache),991(jenkins),994(docker)
```

Jenkins uses the following permissions (validated with executing `/usr/bin/id` inside of the job):

```
uid=996(jenkins) gid=991(jenkins) groups=991(jenkins)
```

The job failed with the message:

```
[Test4Jenkins] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3692200929413510467.sh
+ /usr/bin/id
uid=996(jenkins) gid=991(jenkins) groups=991(jenkins)
+ echo Hallo
/tmp/jenkins3692200929413510467.sh: line 3: /home/dev/Git/Test.txt: Permission denied
```

So why jenkins hasn´t the permission to write this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have **drwxrwxr-x 3 dev dev 4096** permissions which means that user `dev` can do whatever, users that are in the group `dev` can do whatever, others, including `jenkins` do not have write bit and cannot modify directory content. However, adding this bit by executing `chmod o+w /home/dev/` will resolve the issue nut in the worst way because you are giving to one user permissions on the home folder of another user. Better use some dedicated directory, e.g. `/var/lib/share`. Or even better try to achioeve your goals in such a way that does not require Jenkins to access anything but it's own home folder =) good luck!
P.S. you probably wanted to add `jenkins` user to group `dev`, not `dev` to `jenkins` user